# MySQL Group and Concat multiple columns

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, concatenation, group-concat

I have to add two or more strings from MySQL database, for this I used `CONCAT()` function.

Here is the first table `classes` which stores PHP classes.

```
class_id  class_name
--------  ----------
       1  accountant
       2  attendance
```

Another table `methods` which stores each class methods.

```
class_id  method_name            
--------  -----------------------
       1  __construct            
       1  add_expenses

       2  __construct            
       2  attendance_report
```

And I write the query for concatenation.

```
SELECT 
  `cc`.`class_id`,
  `cc`.`class_name`,
  CONCAT(`cm`.`method_name`, ',') AS `method_name` 
FROM
  `classes` AS `cc` 
  LEFT JOIN `methods` AS `cm` 
    ON `cm`.`class_id` = `cc`.`class_id` 
GROUP BY `cc`.`class_name`;
```

Which is not working. My expected output is

```
class_id  class_name      method_name 
--------  --------------  ------------
       1  accountant      __construct, add_expenses, .... n
       2  attendance      __construct, attendance_report, .... n
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

**[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**

instead of

`CONCAT`

`GROUP_CONCAT(cm.method_name)` you do not needs to pass comma as separator that will be taken default.